# pg_pconnect and SET TIMEZONE

Tags: php, postgresql

I have multiple connections to PostgreSQL server opened with pg_pconnect(). If I use:

```
SET TIMEZONE TO 'XYZ';
```

To one of the connections, does it means that the other open connections get same TIMEZONE parameter changed as well?

Do the different connections opened with pg_pconnect share something?

Comment: "Do the different connections opened with pg_pconnect share something?" -- they share a database data, obviously: transactions may be affected by other transactions, depending on isolation lavel. Connections does not share any settings set by `SET` command (according to docs). Is there anything else you are interested in?

Comment: Persistent connections don't share the settings in the sense that the settings are still local, but they reuse them. Starting with the settings left by a previous connection may be seen as a form of "sharing", depending on your interpretation of the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [postgres docs for SET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set.html):

> SET only affects the value used by the current session.

So the answer is no, other open connections are not affected by `SET`, issued in current connection.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on if PHP reuses the persistent connection for the page it renders that might have another user that should have a different time zone?